# How do I get multiple images from aws-s3 in one request and return the base64 datastream? [MERN app]

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a page in my app which has 3 images which are stored in AWS S3.

I've been able to get it to work for a single image, but I can't understand how to get all of them at once. As an aside, I'm using a POST route because I'm sending an array of S3 "key" values stored in my database when the images get uploaded to s3.

```
//fn to get the object from the bucket
async function getImage(img) {
    const data = s3.getObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: img
    }).promise()
    return data
}

//req which receives an array of Keys, of which I'm just using 1 for testing
//and converts encodes it into the datastream which I'm using for the src client-side.

router.post('/s3get', (req, res, next) => {
    function encode(data) {
        let buf = Buffer.from(data);
        let base64 = buf.toString('base64');
        return base64
    }
    getImage(req.body.images[0])
        .then((img) => {
            let imageb64 = encode(img.Body);
            res.json({
                image: imageb64
            })
        }).catch((e) => {
            res.send(e)
        })
}
```

This code is working for retrieving a single image but how do I get all 3?

AWS S3 does not have a built in method for retrieving multiple Objects at once that I am aware of, so I need to retrieve them all one by one, then combine the results.

But how do I do that within a single request, then send a json object back to my front-end containing the 3 image base64 encoded values? like:

```
res.json({
  images: [img1, img2, img3]
})
```

I was experimenting with "Promise.all()" but can't seem to figure out how to work the encoding in there and deal with each one properly.

```
    router.post('/s3get', (req, res, next) => {
        const {images} = req.body
        function encode(data) {
            let buf = Buffer.from(data);
            let base64 = buf.toString('base64');
            return base64
        }
        const responses = await Promise.all(
            images.map((img) => s3.getObject({
                Bucket: 'energitransport',
                Key: img
            }).promise())
        )
        console.log(responses)
    }
```

I was getting this back, but I was seeing the same data 3 times so first off I'm not sure why it's not iterating through each Key value. I confirmed each key value was present by console.log within the map function...so idk. Secondly I can't figure out how to work in the encoding in there and return a single json object.

```
[
  {
    AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
    LastModified: 2022-09-16T07:15:32.000Z,
    ContentLength: 22332,
    ETag: '"notTheActualDataHere"',
    ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    Metadata: { fieldname: 'Testing Metadata' },
    Body: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 00 fc 00 00 01 87 08 06 00 00 00 94 39 3f d1 00 00 00 01 73 52 47 42 00 ae ce 1c e9 00 00 00 04 ... 22282 more bytes>
  },
```